# Add/Replace something with silence DaVinci Resolve

Tags: editing, audio, davinci-resolve

Thank you for helping me. Now, my question is quite simple but I can't find the answer: **How can you add silence in DaVinci Resolve?** I'm switching from **Audacity** to Fairlight and in Audacity, I just replaced breathing with silence to not make the recording shorter, but cut out the sound. Is something **like this possible** in Fairlight or is there **another solution**?

I searched on this site, on youtube and just on the internet. **Thanks!**

Comment: Have you ever considered doing trainings like "FAIRLIGHT AUDIO POST"? For Version 16 it says (page 209): "Filling in Gaps with Room Tone
Nothing screams amateur video more than hearing background sound change between
every cut, or worse, plunging into a black hole of silence between dialogue lines. In
dialogue tracks, silence is deadly! Unless your scene takes place in the vacuum of space,
actual silence should never be present in your soundtrack."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it’s a good idea to replace unwanted sounds with “room tone,” rather than absolute silence.  To do this, you would edit in a recording of the environment where no one is speaking.

In the cases where you do want absolute silence, you can simply delete the audio.   If you set the sequence out point on the deliver page first, you can be sure that the duration doesn’t change.

Alternatively, you can disable the clip, by highlighting the clip and pressing “D.” This is a temporary and nondestructive method, and as long as the clip is disabled, it won’t contribute to any rendered output.

Also, in edit selection mode (it’s the I-beam cursor icon in Fairlight), you can simply drag the long, horizontal gain line down to zero, and automation points will automatically be added wherever in and out points intersect the clip.  If there’s not a long, horizontal gain line visible across clips, you can enable it in the “track display options” menu.